# Adding an attachment to the EmailAuthor page

Tags: email, attachment

I would like to have a button on an opportunity page that generates and saves a pdf as an attachment object and then opens the `/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor` page **with the attachment already attached**.

I've found several good articles on saving the pdf as an attachment, such as [this one from Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/14/attach-a-pdf-to-a-record-in-salesforce/), but even though I've googled around, I haven't been able to find a parameter of the EmailAuthor page that I can assign the attachment id to.

I'm hoping I can avoid writing a visualforce page for this and would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: that article mentioned to create the attachment but how can we get the document id.
How to get the doc_id=01590000000aWn9 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a Document instead of Attachment.

You can pass Document ID in "doc_id" parameter in the URL like this:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?doc_id=01590000000aWn9
```

Comment: How to get the doc_id=01590000000aWn9 ?