# Attach a file on a case and send it through email

Tags: case, customer-community

The nature of our work requires us to send documents back and forth between ourselves and our clients.

I can't find a way to attach a file on a case, let alone send it through e-mail.

I tried:

- To add a new field as an attachment on Customize -> Case -> Fields, but there's no field for files.
- To Attach a file on a case feed, works fine, but how can I send it to the user's email?

**WORKFLOW**

I set up a workflow that e-mails the client on case creation & edition, it would be simply perfect if there was a way to upload a file on salesforce and the user receives it with the case details.

**Bottom line**

I really need to send files to clients.

Answer (score 1):

*(Too long for a comment)*

Most (if not all) standard objects have ["Notes & Attachments"](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_add.htm) related list available. It's not a "field" on a Case, it's a related list. If you don't see it - check your Case page layout? It might have something to do with your permissions but if you're a system administrator I doubt it.

You should also see a related list about Activities (or two) with "Send an Email" button. If you do not see that button and you're in sandbox environment - check the "Deliverability" menu in Setup as discussed in [Service Cloud Console: Data Not Available Error while replying to case via email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22084/service-cloud-console-data-not-available-error-while-replying-to-case-via-email). This should matter only in sandbox and not on production org.

---

As for workflow / email alert that would automatically pick all attachments of "that" case I'm not sure... Probably it would need some heavy lifting with visualforce. But you should be able to attach documents to Email Template used in that workflow and read about mail merging in the help... Or dump the workflow and use a trigger for that?

[Adding an attachment to the EmailAuthor page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13339/adding-an-attachment-to-the-emailauthor-page)

[Send an email with files attached with a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/send-an-email-with-files-attached-with-a-trigger)

Comment: Also, for the "send on upload" scenario, an Attachment trigger would suffice.